# Function of "&!" in csh

Tags: csh

`a.csh` is a c shell script which prints certain messages.
What does the following line do?

```
source a.csh > &! b.log
```

After executing, the `b.log` file contains the output of `a.csh`. But what is the function of "`&!`"?

Answer (score 1):

`>name` redirects stdout to `name`; `>&` redirects stdout and stderr to `name`, and `>!` overrides the `noclobber` setting to prevent accidentally overwriting existing files.

They can be combined as `>&!name` to redirect stdout and stderr to `name`, overriding the `noclobber` setting.

In your example, the space between the `>` and `&!` makes it look like it's two different operators, but it's just `>&!`.

Also see `man csh` (search for `>&`):

```
   > name
   >! name
   >& name
   >&! name
           The file name is used as standard output.  If the file does not
           exist  then it is created; if the file exists, it is truncated,
           its previous contents being lost.

           If the shell variable noclobber is set, then the file must  not
           exist  or  be  a  character  special  file (e.g., a terminal or
           `/dev/null') or an error results.  This helps prevent  acciden‐
           tal  destruction  of  files.  In this case the `!' forms can be
           used to suppress this check.  If notempty is given  in  noclob‐
           ber,  `>'  is  allowed  on  empty  files;  if  ask  is  set, an
           interacive confirmation is presented, rather than an error.

           The forms involving `&' route the diagnostic  output  into  the
           specified  file  as  well  as  the  standard  output.   name is
           expanded in the same way as `<' input filenames are.
```

("Diagnostic output" is csh-speak for stderr).